# Parse fetch() JSON response output Nodejs vs. parse JSON variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, response, fetch-api

I have a question which I am hoping someone can help me with.  I was hoping someone could explain to me the difference between parsing a Variable JSON object vs parsing `fetch()` response data JSON object which is put to a variable.  For instance:

If I have a variable like:

```
var myJSON = 
{
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "T0lDX0J1aWxkX0FydGlmYWN0czpmODk4YjM5MDNjYjk5YzU5NjgzNTk3ZWRjNWFmZjliYw",
    "repository" : "Build_Artifacts",
    "format" : "raw",
    "group" : "/",
    "name" : "05baf31c20d15edb2c477fa4e7bd2427504d3dba_DATE_2020-04-10_TIME_11_09_36.zip",
    "version" : null,
    "assets" : [ {
      "downloadUrl" : "http://localhost:8081/repository/Build_Artifacts/05baf31c20d15edb2c477fa4e7bd2427504d3dba_DATE_2020-04-10_TIME_11_09_36.zip",
      "path" : "05baf31c20d15edb2c477fa4e7bd2427504d3dba_DATE_2020-04-10_TIME_11_09_36.zip",
      "id" : "T0lDX0J1aWxkX0FydGlmYWN0czphNDc1N2JjYWE2MmI2MzA2MDdlMTA1NGE4NTk1MDQ1OQ",
      "repository" : "Build_Artifacts",
      "format" : "raw",
      "checksum" : {
        "sha1" : "040e517528c05ca335a38e98c7ab8673773314bd",
        "sha512" : "652e624873da778dce4bc417cacfead12bdd2ad01e9f7f77cba80270caa0f99caa09d4fb53f584a4da9991186f78bd7b55da1e4ed3f22e026b8333dd332b3b83",
        "sha256" : "b66805d15702505f708b90f6e1169c79390d59b9f8cadc9ab1852f48eeabbfe2",
        "md5" : "60fdd406e026330c2cfbec3e15e05414"
      }
    } ]
  }]
}
```

Then I can parse it via:

```
console.log(myJSON.items[0].name)
// Output is as follows:
// 05baf31c20d15edb2c477fa4e7bd2427504d3dba_DATE_2020-04-10_TIME_11_09_36.zip
```

However, if I get the exact same JSON from fetch and put it to a variable like so:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const asset = 'Build_Artifacts'
const url2 = 'http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository='
const myHeaders = {
    "Authorization": "Basic token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
}


const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(url2 + asset, requestOptions);
    const myJSON = await res.json()
    //console.log(myJSON)
    return myJSON
}
getData().then(res = (myJSON) => {
    console.log(myJSON.items[0].name)

})

// Output is as follows:
// UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I realize that `fetch()` is async and it because of that it returns the response in the form of a promise.  I also have read the response data is in the form of a stream.  Can someone confirm if my fetch output is undefined because I am trying to parse stream data?  If that is the case, then can someone assist with a small example on how I can get fetch data and parse it to retrieve only the data I want to view?

Comment: What does `console.log(myJSON)` returns inside `getData()` and `getData().then()`?

Comment: What is `res = ` doing in `.then(res = (myJSON) => { ... })`? The error says that `myJSON.items` is `undefined`, so it might not be what you expect.

Comment: I just used that to represent that I was going to do something with the data after I pull the entire JSON payload from getData such as parse myJSON.....Even when I remove the entire ".then" and attempt to parse it from getData() I still come up with the same "undefined" response....

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this?

```js
fetch(url2 + asset, requestOptions).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {res = data;})
```

Also see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#:%7E:text=Checking%20that%20the%20fetch%20was%20successful)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following seems to be working:

```html
const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(url2 + asset, requestOptions);
    const myJSON = await res.text()
    return myJSON
}

getData().then(function (result) {
    const resultArr = [];
    const outObjA = JSON.parse(result);
        for (let i=0; i < outObjA.items.length; i++) {
            const fileName = outObjA.items[i].name
            resultArr.push(fileName)
        }
    console.log(resultArr)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error:', error)
  })
```

The for loop allows me to iterate through the entire JSON response for all items.name and dumps them into the resultArr array.

Answer (score -2):

you could modify myJson variable to be formatted like this :

```
var myJson = [{items: {...}}]
```

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but the format of the response seems to be good, i.e. valid JSON....it's parsing the response that I am having a difficult time with.  Are you saying if I format my "myJSON" variable like above it will parse it as the response comes in?